# Отредактировать ссылку Dropbox

Tags: ссылка, dropbox

Какое-то время назад ссылки на файлы в Dropbox изменились с вида:

```
https://dl.dropbox.com/s/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/name.mp4
```

на:

```
https://dl.dropbox.com/scl/fi/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/name.mp4?rlkey=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
```

Можно ли этот **rlkey** запихать **внутрь ссылки**, чтобы после расширения имени файла ничего не было?

Comment: Здесь эта тема обсуждается, но конкретных ответов нет  https://www.dropboxforum.com/t5/Create-upload-and-share/New-URLs-for-shared-links-affecting-3rd-party-integrations/m-p/695726

Answer (score 0):

Plyr HTML5 media player никак не хотел воспроизводить ссылки .mp4 с параметрами после **?**
Добавил в конец **&.mp4** , не знаю, правильно ли это, но плеер начал играть такие ссылки.

```
https://dl.dropbox.com/scl/fi/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/name.mp4?rlkey=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx&.mp4
```

Проверил голый код с плеером Plyr - ссылки с параметрами на конце работают.
Но у меня этот плеер подключается и работает (появляется во всплывающем окне) в скрипте лайтбокса GLightbox.
Здесь скрипт https://github.com/biati-digital/glightbox/blob/master/dist/js/glightbox.js
А тут ссылки с "окончаниями" не работали, пока в конец не добавил **&.mp4**
Понимаю, что надо дописывать что-то в этот скрипт **glightbox.js**, но языка не знаю.
Вопрос оказался сугубо частным случаем работы сторонних скриптов, а Dropbox здесь ни при чём.